# DataRepeater OnCommand multiple CommandArgument

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Is it possible to pass several arguments inside a `CommandArgument` parameter to the `ItemCommand` handler for the ASP.NET Repeater?

I have a table that I render with several columns, pretty basic, I just need one `linkbutton`, when clicked on it, I need to pass 3 parameters to the `onclick` function, all three are the data bound parameters. There doesn't seem to be a way of doing so, aside from using CSV format(which will not work for me, since the values themselves can contain commas).

So, is this possible to pass `p_field1`, `p_field2` and `p_field3` as per in the code below. 
Thanks!

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptId" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" OnItemCommand="rptId_ItemCommand">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                <tr align="center" class='<asp:Literal ID="litRowClass" runat="server" />'>
                                    <td><%#Eval("p_field1")%></td>
                                    <td><%# Eval("p_field2")%></td>
                                    <td><%# Eval("p_field3")%></td>
                                    <td><%# Eval("p_field4")%></td>

                                    <td><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkBtnId" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("p_field1") %>' CommandName="testCommandName">MARK</asp:LinkButton></td>                  




                                </tr> 
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: CSV must not necessarily be a list of comma-separated-values but you could use what you want as separator(f.e. the pipe |). You could easily split these values on serverside.

Comment: That's the thing, the variable can contain text, any text. So I would like to do it the proper civilized way instead of a backwards way. Seems that the data bound values already brought to the server should be accessible to the datarepeater? looks like it's not the case. aghghg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't pass in multiple fields without a "CSV" style format; only a single string is allowed.

You'll have to do some string concatenation and then split it back out OnCommand. Pick some delimiter that won't be in your parameters, below I used `|`.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptId" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" OnItemCommand="rptId_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr align="center" class='<asp:Literal ID="litRowClass" runat="server" />'>
            <td><%#Eval("p_field1")%></td>
            <td><%# Eval("p_field2")%></td>
            <td><%# Eval("p_field3")%></td>
            <td><%# Eval("p_field4")%></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkBtnId" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("p_field1") + "|" + Eval("p_field2") + "|" + Eval("p_field3")  %>' CommandName="testCommandName">MARK</asp:LinkButton></td>                  
        </tr> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

You'd then need something like the following in `rptId_ItemCommand`:

```
string[] arguments = CommandEventArgs.CommandArgument.Split('|');
```

Comment: hmmmmm, so basically the bound data values are not accessible on the server side at all? I mean, they are already bound....I am at awe at MS's idiocy(if that's the case)

Comment: I marked it as an answer, but I am switching my code to use GridView

Comment: The catch is that the repeater might not be bound to the same data on postback; MS abstracted from the bound object also to avoid serializing all that data as viewstate, etc.  In WPF and other newer technologies, they do have other mechanisms to have multiple arguments to commands.  I also don't see why GridView helps.

Comment: Matt, I ended up leaving the Repeater and switching all the needed fields to use Label control. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975140/asp-net-repeater-individual-cells/4975226#4975226

Answer (score 1):

```
CommandArgument='<%# JoinFields(Eval("p_field1"), Eval("p_field2"), Eval("p_field3")) %>'
```

You could use what you want as separator(f.e. the pipe |). You could easily split these values on serverside. To join these field you could use a helper-function like this:

```
Protected Function JoinFields(ByVal p_field1 As Object, ByVal p_field2 As Object, ByVal p_field3 As Object) As String
   Return String.Join("|", New Object() {p_field1, p_field2, p_field3})
End Function
```

Comment: Tim, the text itself can contain any values, including |, ^ or # so I can't use these methods, albeit they seem like the dirty easy workaround. Looks like i have to switch to GridView

Comment: Ok, but i wonder why you have an unique identifier in GridView while you don't have one in repeater.

Comment: I simply don't understand why a gridView makes the difference here. If you can provide a distinct key in the GridView to identify the record(for editing, deleting etc. purposes), you must be able to do this in Repeater too.

Comment: Repeater.Rows property is unavailable. GridView.Rows property IS available. It seems that Repeater was created only for display purposes and it lacks any possible useful functionality.

Comment: No, but repeater holds an item-collection in Items property. You should handle the ItemDataBound event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx