# ASP.net Repeater individual cells

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Is it possible to grab the cell data from Repeater items property such as

Dim test As String = myRepeater.Items(index).DataItem(2)

where myRepeater has x rows and 10 columns and was bound from the DataTable

Seems like it should be trivial, but looks like individual cells CAN NOT be accessed. Please shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly -- remember, repeaters are very, very simple webcontrols and the repeater itself really has a limited idea of what is underneath it.

But you can easily get at items within. The best method is to use a control within the item to help you find stuff. EG, given this repeater "row":

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="theButton" text="Click Me!" OnClick="doIt" /> <asp:TextBox id="theTextBox" value="Whateeavs" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

You can use the button's click handler to find other items in the row:

```
protected void doIt(object s, EventArgs e) {
   var c = (Control)s;
   var tbRef = c.NamingContainer.FindControl("theTextBox");
   var tb = (ITextControl)tbRef;
   doSomethingWith(tb.Text);
}
```

Typically much cleaner than finding things in rows using absolute positioning -- you don't have to worry about indexes and such.

PS: it has been a *long* time since I laid down significant web forms code, no garuntees I got the class names, etc, exactly right.